# función para crear un array de objetos

Tags: javascript, array, funciones, objeto

Tengo que tranformar este array:

```
[
  [
    ['firstName', 'Joe'], 
    ['lastName', 'Blow'], 
    ['age', 42], 
    ['role', 'clerk']
  ],
  [
    ['firstName', 'Mary'], 
    ['lastName', 'Jenkins'], 
    ['age', 36], 
    ['role', 'manager']
  ]
]
```

En este array de objetos:
[{firstName: 'Joe', lastName: 'Blow', age: 42, role: 'clerk'},
 {firstName: 'Mary', lastName: 'Jenkins', age: 36, role: 'manager'}]

Mi funcion es la siguiente:

```js
function transformEmployeeData(array) {
  var obj = {}; 
  var final = [];

  for(var i = 0; i<array.length; i++){
    var general = array[i];
    for(var n = 0; n<general.length; n++){
      var data = general[n];
      var first = data.shift();
      var last = data.pop();
      obj[first] = last;
    }
    // console.log(obj);
    final.push(obj);
    console.log(final);
  }
}
```

El console.log() me regresa los dos objetos que necesito:

```
{ firstName: 'Joe', lastName: 'Blow', age: 42, role: 'clerk' }

{ firstName: 'Mary',
  lastName: 'Jenkins',
  age: 36,
  role: 'manager' }
```

Pero al hacer el push() me regresa esto:

```
[ { firstName: 'Joe', lastName: 'Blow', age: 42, role: 'clerk' } ]
[ { firstName: 'Mary',
    lastName: 'Jenkins',
    age: 36,
    role: 'manager' },
  { firstName: 'Mary',
    lastName: 'Jenkins',
    age: 36,
    role: 'manager' } ]
```

Agradezco sus comentarios y ayuda, saludos a todos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que `obj` siempre es el mismo objeto, que has metido dos veces en el array. Piensa que los metes en final por referencia, no por valor.

```
function transformEmployeeData(array) { 
  var final = [];

  for(var i = 0; i<array.length; i++){
    var general = array[i];
    var obj={};
    for(var n = 0; n<general.length; n++){
      var data = general[n];
      var first = data.shift();
      var last = data.pop();
      obj[first] = last;
    }
     // console.log(obj);
     final.push(obj);
     console.log(final);
  }
}
```

De todos modos, el código podría simplificarse usando `map` y `reduce`. Algo como:

```
function transformEmployeeData(array) {
  var final = array.map( employee => 
    employee.reduce( (obj, data) => { 
      obj[data[0]] = data[1]; return obj; 
    }, {}) 
  });
  return final
 }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias me ayudaste mucho!! Aún no conozco map ni reduce voy a revisarlo. :D

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo con **JSON.parse()** y **JSON.stringify()**

Aquí un ejemplo con tu mismo código

```js
var array = [ [['firstName', 'Joe'], ['lastName', 'Blow'], ['age', 42], ['role', 'clerk']], [['firstName', 'Mary'], ['lastName', 'Jenkins'], ['age', 36], ['role', 'manager'] ] ];
transformEmployeeData(array);
function transformEmployeeData(array) {
  var obj = {};
  var final = [];
  var arrayJson = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(array));
  for(var i = 0; i<arrayJson.length; i++){
  obj = {};  // <-- Se limpia la variable objeto para que no almacene más de una referencia
    var general = array[i];
    for(var n = 0; n<general.length; n++){
      var data = general[n];
      var first = data.shift();
      var last = data.pop();
      obj[first] = last;
    }
    final.push(obj);
  }  
   console.log(final);
 }
```